# Load and add code to external swf with bytearray?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, arrays

I would like to know if it is possible to load an external movie and add code with ByteArray inside, in order to add anymore properties, functions or why not Sprites?

Regards,

Stephane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a lookk at: **as3swf** https://github.com/claus/as3swf/wiki

> as3swf is a low level Actionscript 3
>   library to parse, create, modify and
>   publish SWF files.

Comment: Is there a documentation and exemples to start with this library?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that does this in the API.
I'm not sure if it's possible to hack using byteArray.

You could load a swf, call it's methods (using localConnection) and layer images on top of it.